# Making a module pre-include another (module inheritance) ruby

Tags: ruby, module

I have two Ruby `Module`s where one logically 'inherits' from the other:

```
module FileBacked
  attr_reader :file
  def file=( path )
    @file    = path
    @content = File.read(path,encoding:'utf-8') if File.exist(path)
  end
  def save!
    File.open(@file,'w:utf-8'){ |f| f << @content } if @file
  end
end

module XMLBacked
  attr_reader :doc
  def file=( path )
    super
    @doc = Nokogiri.XML(@content)
  end
  def save!
    @content = @doc.to_xml
    super
  end
end
```

So that the calls to `super` will work, they need to be used like so:

```
class Foo
  include FileBacked # Always include this first
  include XMLBacked  # Always include this second
end

p Foo.ancestors
#=> [Foo, XMLBacked, FileBacked, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

I would like to be able to just write:

```
class Bar
  include XMLBacked  # Also includes FileBacked
end
```

…but I cannot figure out how to do so in a way that causes `FileBacked` to come after `XMLBacked` when searching the method hierarchy.

If I hack in the inclusion, the result is the wrong lookup order:

```
module XMLBacked
  def self.included(klass)
    klass.instance_eval{ include FileBacked }
  end
end

class Jim
  include XMLBacked
end
p Jim.ancestors
#=> [Jim, FileBacked, XMLBacked, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

How can I make including `XMLBacked` cause `FileBacked` to be included in the lookup chain after `XMLBacked`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is present in a duplicate question, though I didn't see it at first:

```
module XMLBacked
  include FileBacked
  # other XMLBacked methods here
end
```

This causes `FileBacked` to be injected into the lookup chain before `XMLBacked` whenever `XMLBacked` it is included.